# Fit function in sklearn KNN model does not work: 'n_neighbors does not take <class 'float'> value, enter integer value'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I am working on a project where I want to use the KNN model from the sklearn library. I simplified the original problem to the following one. X1, X2 and X3 are the predicters to assign each row to a category (Y- variable), which is either 1 or 2. I used a online instruction and all went fine untill I use the fit function. Here is the code:

```
#Importing necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Imports for KNN models
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
#Imports for testing the model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#Import the data file
data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Python/Colab Notebooks/Onlyinttest.csv")

#Split data
X = data.loc[:,['X1','X2','X3']]

Y = data.loc[:,'Y']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)

#Determine k by using sqrt
import math
k = math.sqrt(len(Y_test))
print(k)
#Make k uneven
k = k-1

#KNN Model
classifer = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, p=2,metric='euclidean')
classifer.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

The error: ''n_neighbors does not take <class 'float'> value, enter integer value''

All the data from the original data were float data, but in every online example I read the algorithm also works with float data, so I do not understand this error.

To double check I created the csv used in the code above (Onlyinttest.csv), which only contains int values, but still the some error occures:
[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxnVW.png)

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the future, it is better to offer the data in a more reproducible format. This could be accomplished with `data.to_dict()` in your environment. Then reconstruct the the data DataFrame for the SO question using `data = pd.DataFrame(sample_dictionary)` where you also provide `sample_dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `k` is a float, not an integer. The `n_neighbors` value in `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, p=2,metric='euclidean')` has to be an integer, not a float.

You could convert k into an integer in this example using the `math.ceil()` function which return the integer that is equal to or greater than the float value. Alternately, you could use the `math.floor()` function which will return the integer that less than or equal to the input float.

For example:

```
#Determine k by using sqrt
import math
k = math.sqrt(len(Y_test))
print(k)
#Make k uneven
k = k-1
k = math.ceil(k)
print(k)  # should now be an integer
print(type(k))  # <class 'int'>

#KNN Model
classifer = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, p=2, metric='euclidean')
classifer.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```